# How to execute an OrderSend() function of MQL4 or MQL5 using cmd?

Tags: mql4, mql5, forex

How to execute an **`OrderSend()`** function of MQL4 or MQL5 language using cmd script ?

Comment: interesting question, but could you be more specific? Are you talking a Windows **cmd** type script, Windows powershell or linux style or something else? It would be more helpful, if you could provide an example of what you want to do.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> How to execute an `OrderSend()` function of MQL4 or MQL5 language using a cmd script ?

Doable.

Both sides of your wished eco-system can get connected using ZeroMQ or [nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg) signalling/messaging.

The cmd shell will **`PUSH`** such instruction, next the MT4/MT5 Terminal will detect a message on a **`PULL`**-socket archetype an submit properly formatted **`OrderSend(...)`** instruction and handle the XTO-related error-state(s) and all the Order-Management related duties.

The MQL4/5 side will best work using the Script-form of the MQL4/5 code-execution units, which will release your code from being a `QUOTE`-arrival event dependent.

Comment: Your answer is probably correct, but the language you use to describe it is way to technical. TBH, I have no idea what you talking about, and i have been working with MQL4 for quite some time, so some clarification would be appreciated. How about an example, demonstrating your point?

Comment: ^^ That said, you may want to consider all the answer of yours, that I have **up-voted**!